# appending multiple string querys into httpclientmodule

Tags: angular, http

Why does this not work? my params is sent empty on the request, i need to iterate through a list of dates and send them as query parameters

```
public ObterSimulacao<T>(inscricao:string,listaDatas: string[]){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    listaDatas.forEach(data => {
        params
        .append('listDate',data)
    });
    return this.http.get<T>(this._obterSimulacaoUrl + inscricao ,{params});
}
```

Comment: I think `HttpParams` is for a request body rather than query string parameters.

Comment: Another thing: this piece listaDatas.forEach(data => { params.append('listDate',data) }) does not make much sense, because you will be overwriting the 'listDate' key in every iteration. It should be a different key/param for each iteration.

Comment: I dont think thats correct im doing something similar in one of my dotnet API's      foreach (var date in listDate)
            {
                builder.AddQueryString("listDate", date.ToString());
            } and it doesnt get overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `append` method incorrectly, check following:

```
public ObterSimulacao<T>(inscricao:string,listaDatas: string[]){
    let params = new HttpParams();
    listaDatas.forEach(data => {
        params = params.append('listDate', data)
    });
    return this.http.get<T>(this._obterSimulacaoUrl + inscricao ,{params});
}
```

Comment: didnt really work =/ this is the request url localhost:50441/api/v1/Movimento/Simulacao/1042790001801?listDate=2019-01-01,2020-02-02                   what it should be ?listDate=2019-01-01&listDate=2020-02-02

Comment: @DanielBezerraDeMenezes oh, Okay. Updated the answer. It should work.

Comment: ye lol, i ended up tryng params = params on my example, no idea why i need to do that in order to work. thanks for your time tho